# scrapy prevent downloading files if already downloaded

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a scraper which downloads all file from a website and saves the download links in a `JSON` file using an item pipeline. How to prevent the scraper from downloading the same file again if its link is found in the `JSON` file.

Comment: Show the code that you've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! The fact is that what you want to do is quite complex to do programmatically in a generic way (you have to write your own middleware or to customise RFPDupeFilter [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L28) . But you are very lucky. Another generic way to achieve exactly what you want is just [pausing and resuming crawls](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#jobs-pausing-and-resuming-crawls) which is already implemented and tested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @neverlastn I thought duplicate filtering was the default behaviour ["Both pipelines implement these features: : Avoid re-downloading media that was downloaded recently"](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#downloading-and-processing-files-and-images),

Comment: @Steve of course de-dump is there by default but there is no API for pre-loading those de-dupers with a set of initial URLs to ignore. This is what is asked for here :-)

Comment: Actually while reading the source code trying to find out how to implement such a feature I discovered the pause/resume functionality.